# Transparent Tabpage to show Desktop (wallpaper and Icons)

Tags: vb.net

With winforms, you can set Transparency of a form via setting up the TransparencyKey and the Backcolor of the form into the same color in the properties window.

However, the tabpages in the TabControl doesn't have these properties.

How will I make it so that a tabpage will show the desktop's contents?

Also, is there a way for me to show the icons in my desktop on the tabpage? The icons must still function as normal(can be double clicked to open the file, single clicked to rename and can be dragged around inside my tabpage.)

I am using VB.NET 2005. Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have a look at [http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4906] 
It has a sample you are looking for... Windows Explorer designing in winforms

Comment: my apologies, the link you are pointing to returns an error for me.

Comment: ohk.. go on this http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Comment: I've seen this complaint before.  Apparently there's been trouble with Aero on some Windows versions, it implements this kind of transparency very differently from the way it was done before.  Never seen this problem myself however.  Picking the right key color appears to be important.  I always pick Color.Fuchsia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly, the answer is quite simple.

Just set the `TransparencyKey` of a form to a color that you wish to appear as transparent, then set the backcolor of the tabpage to that color (the color you've set on your form).